# postman "Error: ValidationError: username: Path `username` is required."

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I am trying to test my routes using the postman.
The below is my user.model.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 3
  },
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

My router file for the user is below

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    User.find()
        .then(users => res.json(users))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + error));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;

    const newUser = new User({ username });

    newUser.save()
        .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + error));
});

module.exports = router;
```

each time when I am trying to test the post route for user I am getting "Error: ValidationError: username: Path `username` is required." error
below is the screenshot of my postman [image]

Could anyone please help me in figuring out where I am wrong.

Comment: are you getting req.body.username in your router ?

Comment: By adding header as below, it works. Click the Headers button in Postman and put value     Content-Type   application/json

Answer (score 12):

The data you passed should be in JSON format and not in multi-part format. Change your Postman request as following and check.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I could solve the problem by adding the next parts in my program:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

My bodyparser version was "^1.15.2"

Comment: This was the solution for me. Was driving me nuts for the last couple of hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change your /add router:

const newUser = new User({ username : username }); // change

You have to pass your username this way.Hope this will help you.if you have any error though then let me know.

Comment: @Prakesh Karena if I will remove required property from username field then I am able to post my information to my route

Comment: have you check your database store username or not?